# Redux reducer add todo using spread operator

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using redux promise middleware and this is my reducer for add todo

```
case 'POST_TODO_FULFILLED':
      return { 
          ...state, 
          loading: false, 
          data: {...state.data, ...action.playload.response.data},
          added: true
      }
```

something is wrong with the spread operator, but why?

Comment: Assuming data to is an array, it should be `data: [...state.data, ...action.playload.response.data],`

Comment: are you getting any error? if yes, please add it to the question.

Comment: `playload` looks like a typo